# Android app doesn't read input boxes

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I put a `WebBrowser` component in my app because I have to display a webpage. The webpage also contains an `input` box.

```
<input name="nome" style="width:160px" type="text" />
```

This is the HTML code I wrote. By the way, when I click on it with my Samsung device because I must type some text, the keyboard doesn't appear.

What could I do?

You can see the webpage here: [click](http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/android_ios/sendrecor_due.html)

Comment: You've posted one line of HTML from some anonymous web page, totally out of context, with no other information about the page. How are we supposed to tell you why it doesn't work? What else does the web page contain? Does it have a form element? Does it have a button that submits the input somewhere? (If it doesn't, there's no reason to get the input, because it obviously does nothing with it.) You'll need to provide much more information to get help. As it is now, it's the same as "I have 'if (i + j = k) then', but it doesn't work. What's wrong?".

Comment: In general such criticism is probably justified. But in this case the issue is so general and obvious that I don't think it really warranted more detail.

*Any* browser functionality on a mobile device should surely pop up the keyboard when you click on an input box, right? Delphi's browser component does not. Yet.

Comment: Yes sorry, I thought that was enough. I edited with the link, since the webpage has a very easy HTML code you can look at it with an object inspector.

Comment: In the meantime, perhaps you could add a button to 'manually' open/close the virtual keyboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a known limitation of the web browser component.

It's doubtless findable in Embo's QC database.

It's pending a fix, I gather.

<checks>

Oh yes, here it is: [QC 119313](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=119313)

Also documented in the [Delphi XE5 Release Notes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Release_Notes_for_XE5#WebBrowser_Does_Not_Accept_Keyboard_Input_on_Android)

Comment: So you mean that it's a known problem and I cannot do anything?

Comment: That would appear to be the case, yes.